# WIN 10: Python directory is wrong?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, python, gui, pyqt

I'm not sure how to phrase my problem, and have tried to find similar problems online, but I could not (Perhaps with better phrasing I could, so I am sorry if this is a duplicated question!)

Anyhow, I'm trying to run pyuic5 (to test it works).
So, I open CMD (In the directory my .ui file is) and when I enter **pyuic5** I get:

> Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe" C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Scripts\pyuic5.exe"'

**Note: C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32 is the correct directory**

My PATH variables are correct I believe. I've added all the screenshots I thought may be useful.

[Here is my appdata/local/... folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z52tr.png)

[Here is my CMD window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcW5K.png)

[Here is my PATH variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uvfD.png)

[Here is the command being 'ran'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKaav.png)

[Here is 'pip list' with PyQT highlighted, showing ALL packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbEWn.png)

Please let me know if you need more information, I'm pretty new to python. Thanks guys

[ps I'm using the 32bit version as 64bit caused some issues for me]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running `CMD` as Administrator?
Also, try running `python --version` in `CMD` to verify you python installation. it should output your default python version.

Comment: Yes mate I've tried a few times, the version running comes out with only one result (as expected) = Python 3.7.3

Answer (score 0):

`C:\Program Files (x86)` is a bad place to install Python (and thus its related modules), as spaces in your path(s) can cause scripts to fail.

Likewise, `C:\Program Files` and `C:\Program Files (x86)` are (potentially) treated differently by Windows (as special system folders), meaning this can cause other issues besides just the ones regarding spaces.

As a serious recommendation, I would suggest doing the following:

- Use `pip freeze` (e.g. as `python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt`) to create a current list of your installed modules.
- Uninstall Python 3.7 completely.
- Reinstall Python 3.7 in a path without spaces (e.g. under `C:\Programs\Python37-32` or something similar).
- Use e.g. `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt` to reinstall your current modules.

Even if this doesn't solve your exact problem, this will likely save you an unknown number of headaches in the future.